# WPF Drag&Drop is always enabled if a dialog box is open

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop

In my WPF application, I implemented drag & drop to open files from Windows Explorer
using

- `AllowDrop="True"`
- `DragOver="MainWindow_DragOver"`
- `Drop="MainWindow_Drop"`

no problem, everything works fine.

But if a dialog box is open
I can always do Drag/Drop files from Windows Explorer into the main window of my application.
Have you ever encountered this problem? Can you help me solve it? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If your dialog box is a modal one, it disables the parent window. This can be checked using the [IsWindowEnabled API call](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646303(VS.85).aspx). (I am no WPF expert, but the .IsEnabled or .Focusable properties do not seem to work this way.)

```
void MainWindow_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    bool isEnabled = NativeMethods.IsWindowEnabled(new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle);
    e.Effects = isEnabled ? DragDropEffects.Copy :  DragDropEffects.None;
    e.Handled = true;
}

class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool IsWindowEnabled(IntPtr hWnd);
}
```

see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/6363095/9156214

Comment: This works for me. Bad thing that MS-Windows allows drag drop on disabled windows ... any idea how I could automate that in the whole application without checking the enabled state in each dragover function?

Answer (score 0):

When the dialog box opens, disallow dropping on your main form. Make sure you open a modal dialog (`ShowDialog` instead of `Show`).